# Is it an adverb clause, a relative clause or a noun clause?

Tags: grammar, american-english, clauses, subordinate-clauses

Is it an adverb clause, a relative clause or a noun clause? 
"To get to New Zealand the fastest way"

The whole sentence is... To get to New Zealand the fastest way, you will have to fly from Copenhagen.

Comment: Post comments here only to [ask for more information or suggest improvements](/help/privileges/comment). Avoid answering questions in comments. Other types of comment can be posted in the [main chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) or a chatroom created for the purpose.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the phrase "in order to" function as?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/256299/what-does-the-phrase-in-order-to-function-as)

Comment: What do you suggest it is, and why and with what research?

Answer (score 0):

It's a PP, prepositional phrase, with preposition "for" understood.  The object of the PP is a nominalized sentence with the complementizer "for-to" (compare "For you to get to New Zealand ...").  If the alternative complementizer "(Poss)-ing" is used for the PP object, the preposition "for" can be expressed: "For getting to New Zealand the fastest way, ..."

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69918/discussion-on-answer-by-greg-lee-is-it-an-adverb-clause-a-relative-clause-or-a).